# How to redirect to my website after click accept money in my paypal account?

Tags: paypal

I want to redirect to my website, after I click on accept money button in my account. How do I do?

Hope everyone help me?

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and especially read Why is [“Can someone help me?”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) not an actual question?

Comment: There's no background here. What stage are you at? Do you have a paypal button, do you have an IPN setup, are you trying to redirect from your success page or from paypal itself? Where's your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding you are talking about clicking on "Accept" button that is shown to you once you login into your paypal account.
If yes, then when you click on "Accept" button action is performed on PayPal server and return backs to PayPal page. PayPal does not/cannot provide any handle using which you can go to any other website.